# Disable Shift+Home, Shift+End keybindings in Gnome Terminal / Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

How to disable Shift+Home, Shift+End keybindings in Gnome Terminal / Ubuntu 12.04?
(they scroll to top/bottom).

I already tried:

1. Disable shotcuts in Gnome Terminal Keyboard Shortcuts (no such shortcuts available).
2. Looked into gconf-editor: gnome-terminal and metacity shortcuts (couldn't find Shift+Home or Shift+End shortcuts here).
3. Run gsettings for different schemas, like "gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" - no such shortcuts here.
4. Went through keybindings in CompizConfig Settings. No luck here either.

Is there other way to disable keyboard shortcuts for Gnome Terminal in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Gnome Terminal indeed has predefined actions bound to *Shift + Home* and *Shift + End*. However, it is not GT that defines this behaviour, but rather it's because of VTE which GT is based on. As far as I can tell this aspect is not configurable and the only way to fix it is to patch VTE. I described how to do this in my blog post [Fixing Ctrl-Home, Ctrl-End, Shift-Home, and Shift-End shortcuts in Gnome Terminal in Ubuntu 13.04](http://stepankk-dev.blogspot.ru/2014/02/fixing-ctrl-home-ctrl-end-shift-home.html). Below is mostly a copy-paste of that post.

What I basically had to do was to follow the *Classic* instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81870/how-to-download-modify-build-and-install-a-debian-source-package). I changed them for my particular case.

*Note:* The instructions below are based on Ubuntu 13.04, which I have at hand, but I suppose they can be applied, probably with some minor alterations, to other versions of the distro.

There are two `libvte*` packages in Ubuntu 13.04. So first of all, I had to find out which one Gnome Terminal depends on:

```
$ apt-cache depends gnome-terminal | grep libvte
```

The required version was `libvte-2.90-9`. I downloaded the source code:

```
$ apt-get source libvte-2.90-9
```

Then I modified it:

```
$ cd vte3-0.34.2 
$ vim src/vte.c
```

Here I had to find the unwanted shortcuts, they followed after this comment:

```
/* Keypad/motion keys. */
```

So I just removed everything up to the next comment:

```
/* Let Shift +/- tweak the font, like XTerm does. */
```

It turned out that removing these shortcuts was not enough because of [this VTE's bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600659). So I applied [the patch](https://bug600659.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=265278) mentioned in the comments to the bug:

```
--- a/src/keymap.c
+++ b/src/keymap.c
@@ -284,6 +284,8 @@ static const struct _vte_keymap_entry _vte_keymap_GDK_Home[] = {
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_vt220, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "1~", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_hp, 0, _VTE_CAP_ESC "h", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_nothpvt, 0, X_NULL, 0, "kh"},
+   {cursor_default, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "H", -1, X_NULL},
+   {cursor_app, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "H", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_all, 0, X_NULL, 0, X_NULL},
 };

@@ -291,6 +293,8 @@ static const struct _vte_keymap_entry _vte_keymap_GDK_End[] = {
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_all, 0, X_NULL, 0, "@7"},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_vt220, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "4~", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_notvt220, 0, X_NULL, 0, "@7"},
+   {cursor_default, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "F", -1, X_NULL},
+   {cursor_app, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "F", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_all, 0, X_NULL, 0, X_NULL},
 };

@@ -507,6 +511,8 @@ static const struct _vte_keymap_entry _vte_keymap_GDK_KP_End[] = {
    {cursor_all, keypad_default, fkey_vt220, 0, "1", 1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_app, fkey_notvt220, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "4~", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_app, fkey_vt220, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "q", -1, X_NULL},
+   {cursor_default, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "F", -1, X_NULL},
+   {cursor_app, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "F", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_all, 0, X_NULL, 0, X_NULL},
 };

@@ -568,6 +574,8 @@ static const struct _vte_keymap_entry _vte_keymap_GDK_KP_Home[] = {
    {cursor_all, keypad_default, fkey_vt220, 0, "7", 1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_app, fkey_notvt220, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "1~", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_app, fkey_vt220, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "w", -1, X_NULL},
+   {cursor_default, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_CSI "H", -1, X_NULL},
+   {cursor_app, keypad_all, fkey_default, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "H", -1, X_NULL},
    {cursor_all, keypad_all, fkey_all, 0, X_NULL, 0, X_NULL},
 };

@@ -1279,6 +1287,8 @@ _vte_keymap_key_get_modifier_encoding_method(guint keyval)
    case GDK_KEY (Right):
    case GDK_KEY (Insert):
    case GDK_KEY (Delete):
+   case GDK_KEY (Home):
+   case GDK_KEY (End):
    case GDK_KEY (Page_Up):
    case GDK_KEY (Page_Down):
    case GDK_KEY (KP_Up):
@@ -1287,6 +1297,8 @@ _vte_keymap_key_get_modifier_encoding_method(guint keyval)
    case GDK_KEY (KP_Right):
    case GDK_KEY (KP_Insert):
    case GDK_KEY (KP_Delete):
+   case GDK_KEY (KP_Home):
+   case GDK_KEY (KP_End):
    case GDK_KEY (KP_Page_Up):
    case GDK_KEY (KP_Page_Down):
    case GDK_KEY (F1):
```

There were no conflicts.

Then I rebuilt the package:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep libvte-2.90-9
$ dch -i # here I updated the version to 0.34.2-customized-0ubuntu3
$ debuild -us -uc -b
```

And installed it:

```
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i libvte-2.90-common_0.34.2-customized-0ubuntu3_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libvte-2.90-9_0.34.2-customized-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Although it was enough to install these two packages to fix the problem, I installed all the others that were generated by the `debuild` command as well.

After restarting Gnome Terminal, *Shift + Home* and *Shift + End* started working as expected.

Comment: When linking to something, always provide long enough summary of that content. That link will be broken sooner or later, and after that this post is pretty much useless.